# How to create a general method for multiple UIActionSheet in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uialertcontroller

I'm setting up a `UIViewController` with 2 `UIButtons`. 
Each button will have a function which will show an `UIAlertController` with few options.
It is possible to create a general method to avoid the duplication of code in both functions ?

I already tried to create a function with a parameter of type  `UIAlertController` but I can't manage to use that parameter.

Here I've created an example to show you what I try to refactor:

```
func showFirstMenu(){

    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    let optionOne = UIAlertAction(title: "Option 1", style: .default) { action in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "optionOne", sender: self)
    }

    let optionTwo = UIAlertAction(title: "Option 2", style: .default) { action in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "optionTwo", sender: self)
    }

    actionSheet.addAction(optionOne)
    actionSheet.addAction(optionTwo)
    actionSheet.addAction(cancel)

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad ){
        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = []
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Display on iPad")
    }
    else{
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Display on iPhone")
    }
}

func showSecondMenu(){

    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    let optionThree = UIAlertAction(title: "Option 3", style: .default) { action in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "optionThree", sender: self)
    }

    let optionFour = UIAlertAction(title: "Option 4", style: .default) { action in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "optionFour", sender: self)
    }

    actionSheet.addAction(optionThree)
    actionSheet.addAction(optionFour)
    actionSheet.addAction(cancel)

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad ){
        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = []
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Display on iPad")
    }
    else{
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Display on iPhone")
    }
}
```

It is any way to reduce this amount of code ? Or this is the only way to declare an `UIActionSheet` ?

Thanks if you read this.

Comment: Did you always have 2 options? On either controller..

Comment: No, I can have different numbers of options.

Comment: Then instead of AlertController, better if you create custom popup with tableview.. its more easy and handy. Check out this -> https://github.com/dillidon/alerts-and-pickers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

If your `AlertViewController`'s actions will always have segue to perform you can significantly reduce duplication like below using struct and variadic parameters:

```
struct Option {
    var name: String
    var segueIdentifier: String
}

func configureActionSheet(options: Option...) {
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    actionSheet.addAction(cancel)

    for option in options {
        let currentOption = UIAlertAction(title: option.name, style: .default) { action in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: option.segueIdentifier, sender: self)
        }
        actionSheet.addAction(currentOption)
    }

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad ){
        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = []
    }

    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func showMenu1() {
    let option1 = Option(name: "Option 1", segueIdentifier: "optionOne")
    let option2 = Option(name: "Option 2", segueIdentifier: "optionTwo")
    self.configureActionSheet(options: option1, option2)
}
```

**Solution 2:**

If your `AlertViewController`'s action will always be different then there is not much you can do but still avoid duplication as follows:

```
func configureActionSheet() -> UIAlertController {
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    actionSheet.addAction(cancel)

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad ){
        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = []
    }

    return actionSheet
}


func showFirstMenu() {
    let optionOne = UIAlertAction(title: "Option 1", style: .default) { action in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "optionOne", sender: self)
    }

    let optionTwo = UIAlertAction(title: "Option 2", style: .default) { action in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "optionTwo", sender: self)
    }

    let actionSheet = configureActionSheet()
    actionSheet.addAction(optionOne)
    actionSheet.addAction(optionTwo)
    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function like this

```
func presentActionsheetWithOptions(title:String, msg: String, options:[String:String], isCancelRequired:Bool) {

    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    for (header,seg) in options {
        let optionOne = UIAlertAction(title: header, style: .default) { action in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: seg, sender: self)
        }
        actionSheet.addAction(optionOne)

    }
    if(isCancelRequired) {
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        actionSheet.addAction(cancel)

    }
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad ){
        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = []
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Display on iPad")
    }
    else{
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Display on iPhone")
    }
}
```

Make a function call like

```
        presentActionsheetWithOptions(title: "test", msg: "testmsg", options: ["option1":"optionone","option2":"optiontwo"], isCancelRequired: true);
```

decide on variables that should be optional

Answer (score 0):

You can set a tag in each `UIButton` like this:

```
//For the first button
UIButton.tag = 1

//For the second button
UIButton.tag = 2
```

Then, you pass this tag in your menu function, create an array of your `UIAlertAction` titles and identifiers, loop them and add the proper action to the alert by using the switch method:

```
  func showMenu(sender: UIButton) {
     let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
     let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

     let titles = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]
     let identifiers = ["optionOne","optionTwo","optionThree","optionFour"]
     let tags = [1,1,2,2] //match the button tag with the array index

     for (index, title) in titles.enumerated(){
        if sender.tag == tags[index] {
           let action = self.getAction(title: title, identifier:identifiers[index])
           actionSheet.addAction(action)
        }
      }
      actionSheet.addAction(cancel)
  }

  func getAction(title: String, identifier: String) -> UIAlertAction {
      let action = (title: title, style: .default) { action in
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: identifier, sender: self)
      }
      return action
  }
```

Hope this helps!